# Laravel maatwebsite import and fill a column with a select form

Tags: laravel, table-relationships, excel-import

I'm using maatwebsite's Excel import library to import employees into a database table and it works quite well. However, on the View page where I select the Excel file to import, I have a select drop-down that shows data from the related Companies table, so that that specific selected Company is posted to all the currently imported employees' `Comp_id` foreign key. I have created the `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relations in the respective `Company` and `Employee` models.

The data sent in the EmployeeController:

```
public function viewImport()
{
    $employees = Employee::all(); 
    return view('viewImport', 
        ['companies' => Company::pluck('CompanyName', 'Comp_id')
        ])->withEmployees($employees);
}



 public function importExcel(Request $request)
 {

    if($request->hasFile('import_file')){
        $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();

        $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();

        $company = Company::.....; /*???????????????

        if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){

            foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $value) {
                if(!empty($value)){ 
 foreach ($value as $v) {
     $insert[] = ['name'=> $v['name'],
                  'surname'=> $v['surname'],
                  'idno'=> $v['idno'],
                  'phone'=> $v['phone'],
                  'salary'=> $v['salary'],
                  'dob'=> $v['dob'],
                  'jobdescription'=> $v['jobdescription'],
                  'initials'=> $v['initials'],
                  'Comp_id' => .... /* ???????????????
                 ];
```

I've included the `Company` model as class in the EmployeeController.

I want to add a field insertion `'Comp_id' => ....` with the `Comp_id` value of the selected drop-down. How do I create the $company variable in the function so that the selected `Comp_id` can be inserted for every row? Or is there a completely different way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nailed it with `'comp_id' => $request->get('Comp_id')`.

```
foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($value)){
        foreach ($value as $v) {        
            $insert[] = ['name'=> $v['name'],
             'surname'=> $v['surname'],
             'idno'=> $v['idno'],
             'phone'=> $v['phone'],
             'salary'=> $v['salary'],
             'dob'=> $v['dob'],
             'jobdescription'=> $v['jobdescription'],
             'initials'=> $v['initials'],
             'comp_id' => $request->get('Comp_id'),
            ];
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your view has a form with a select with your `Comp_id`, you should be able to grab it from your incomming [request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-input):

```
$company->comp_id = $request->get('Comp_id');
```

just a hint: have a look at laravel's [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment) feature.

Comment: Thanks for the response @passioncoder. If i use your code in the controller, I get the error

Comment: ... "Creating default object from empty value". I've looked at the mass assignment feature, and the `Comp_id` column is added as `protected $fillable` in the `Employee` model.